# Jetpack Compose ConstraintLayout does not fill width

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I try to make custom tabs using ConstraintLayout. This is the code:

```
@Composable
fun TestSplitScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(10.dp),
            text = "My beautiful title"
        )
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(
                    top = 10.dp,
                )
                .wrapContentHeight()
        ) {
            val (left, right) = createRefs()
            CustomTab(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(left) {
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(right.start)
                        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    },
                title = "First tab",
                isSelected = true,
                background = R.color.at_nobel_grey,
                index = 0
            )
            CustomTab(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(right) {
                        top.linkTo(left.top)
                        start.linkTo(left.end)
                        bottom.linkTo(left.bottom)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                        height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    },
                title = "Second tab",
                isSelected = false,
                background = R.color.at_light_grey,
                index = 1
            )
        }
    }
}
```

as I understand, both tabs has to have same alignment (left, or center). But my tabs are aligned different. The first one is centerred, the second one is left aligned:
[image: Preview]

Here is my code for Tab:

```
@Composable
fun CustomTab(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    isSelected: Boolean = false,
    background: Int,
    index: Int,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    val radioColors = RadioButtonDefaults.colors(
        selectedColor = colorResource(id = R.color.at_blue),
        unselectedColor = colorResource(id = R.color.at_nobel_grey),
        disabledColor = colorResource(id = R.color.at_nobel_grey)
    )
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp, 4.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp))
            .background(color = colorResource(id = background))
            .padding(
                bottom = 4.dp
            )
    ) {
        val (radio, text, badge) = createRefs()
        RadioButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(20.dp)
                .constrainAs(radio) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                },
            selected = isSelected,
            colors = radioColors,
            onClick = {
                onClick()
            }
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(text) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(radio.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                },
            text = title,
            fontSize = 15.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
        if (index == 0) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(badge) {
                        top.linkTo(text.bottom)
                        start.linkTo(text.start)
                    }
                    .background(
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.at_green),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                    )
                    .padding(
                        start = 5.dp,
                        top = 0.dp,
                        end = 5.dp,
                        bottom = 0.dp
                    ),
                text = "my subtitle",
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.at_white),
                fontSize = 10.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to have both left aligned. I also tried to use `Row` instead of `ConstraintLayout`, but in that case both tabs are centerred. Does anyone have any idea, what's wrong in my code?